# Como passar dados de uma tela para outra com Native LocalStorage e Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, localstorage, cordova-plugin

Gostaria de saber como passar os dados de um item para um formulário em outra view, utilizando o Native LocalStorage do Ionic 3.

Criei um provider como mostra a seguir:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

/*
  Generated class for the MovimentosProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class MovimentosProvider {

  lista:any[];
  chave:string = "movimentos";

  constructor(private storage: Storage) {
    this.storage.ready().then(()=>{
      this.storage.get(this.chave).then((registos) =>{
        if(registos){
          this.lista = registos;
        }else{
          this.lista = [];
        }
      });      
    });    
  }

  listar(){
    return this.lista;
  }

  adicionar(registro:any){    
    this.storage.ready().then(()=>{
      this.lista.push(registro);
      this.storage.set(this.chave, this.lista); 
    }); 
  }

}
```

E tenho um botão *`editarMovimento`* mas quero passar o que capturou da listagem para o formulário e poder editar o mesmo.

```
editarMovimento(movimento:IMovimento){    
    this.movimento = movimento;

  }
```

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi exatamente sua pergunta.

Dentro do botão você passa como parâmetro a chave que deseja editar, a mesma que utilizou no storage.set

```
storage.get(SUA CHAVE AQUI).then((val) => {
    console.log(val);
  });
```

Lembrando que o retorno sempre é string, então caso você tenha salvo um objeto será necessário transformar a string em um objeto.

Comment: Obrigado @Renan Rafael, deu certo.